# How to repeat a View inside an already repeated View?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am developing an `android` app and I am facing an issue with `listviews`.
I am using this library so I can use the `swipe effect`. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Lets say I have an `ArrayList<Item>` and the `Item` class also have an `ArrayList<SubItem>`.

As you can see the `ArrayList<Item>` will be used to repeat an View inside `Listview`. Pretty easy until now. The problem is that the `ArrayList<SubItem>` attribute inside `Arraylist<Item>` will also be used to repeat another View, and that is where I am stuck. I have no idea of how to do it and also have not found any example on that library wiki, neither on google or github using that library. Everybody using this library put the multiple xml element manually, hardcoded, but I want to repeat it multiple times programmatically. Check the step 1 on the lib wiki: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/wiki/usage

There is a `surface view` and a `bottom view`. There can be multiple `bottom view` elements, and this is the one I want to repeat in a `Listview` (or it can be any other android feature capable of repeating views).

Can anyone please help me with this?? Any code of someone repeating items inside an already repeated item will be helpful.

Comment: put another listview in your list item view xml layout or you can use for() loop to inflate layout and add that layout in to your main list item layout .

Comment: Will I need another adapter if I put another listview inside that listview? Do you have any example code?

Comment: yes you will need another adapter